# What are the advantages of K means clustering for web logs?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I was referring lot of IEEE papers for clustering of web logs for predicting behavior of a person on e commerce web site.Most of the IEEE papers were applying simple K means clustering but none of them revealed the reason.
Can some one tell me reasons ? 
What are the advantages of K means over other ?
How can we select optimal value for K in this particular case ?

Answer (score 0):

k-means doesn't work that well, but it is the *simplest algorithm* you can find. Plus, it is quite fast.

Maybe they were just too lazy to try something more complicated.